# Componente VUE da error al utilizarlo mas de una vez en una misma página.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

gracias de ante mano por tomarse unos minutos para leer mi problema.

Estoy creando un componente de CARROUSEL en VUE y VUETIFY.

Utilizo lo siguiente:

- Vue.JS (One Single Component.vue)
- Vuetify (Pero sus clases para manejar formatos y colores, no sus componentes UI)

Se producen una serie de errores que a mi entender suceden por existir todos a la vez en la misma "pagina.vue", Por lo que trataré de enfocarme en el problema principal para ser lo mas breve y conciso posible.

problema:

- al importar el componente "carrousellCategorias.vue" en mi "index.vue" este debe renderizar (aparecer) 4 veces, y lo hace pero el primer elemento funciona 90% correctamente y el resto tiene problemas con el css y javascript, Es decir no se ve ni funciona correctamente.

Antes de ir al código dejo una imagen que ilustra el problema.
El primer "Carrousel" al pasar el mouse por encima muestras las flechas correctamente, El resto no. Dentro de mi componente "carrousellCategorias.vue" tengo una función que define que ancho debe tener el contenedor de las imágenes para que solo se muestren 3 y pueda desplazarme de 3 en 3 dentro del array de imágenes de manera tal que en el carrousel siempre visualizo de a 3 imágenes (No te preocupes si no entiendes esto último, lo explicaré mas abajo con el código).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CÓDIGO A CONTINUACIÓN**

Dejare todo el código y dentro del mismo con comentarios explicare los puntos críticos de este.
Notarán que algunos comentarios del código dicen "20 imagenes" se debe a que el array de imagenes contiene 20 de estas. Peor no iba a dejar un array de 20 imagenes aquí porque este es muy amplio.

```js
export default {
  name: "categoryBox",
  props: {categoria:String},
  data() {
    return {
      imageActive:0,
      datafiltrada: [],
      data:[
                {
                    "id":1,
                    "title":"Fjallraven - Foldsack No. 1 Backpack, Fits 15 Laptops",
                    "price":109.95,
                    "description":"Your perfect pack for everyday use and walks in the forest. Stash your laptop (up to 15 inches) in the padded sleeve, your everyday",
                    "category":"men's clothing",
                    "image":"https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "id":2,
                    "title":"Mens Casual Premium Slim Fit T-Shirts ",
                    "price":22.3,
                    "description":"Slim-fitting style, contrast raglan long sleeve, three-button henley placket, light weight & soft fabric for breathable and comfortable wearing. And Solid stitched shirts with round neck made for durability and a great fit for casual fashion wear and diehard baseball fans. The Henley style round neckline includes a three-button placket.",
                    "category":"men's clothing",
                    "image":"https://fakestoreapi.com/img/71-3HjGNDUL._AC_SY879._SX._UX._SY._UY_.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "id":3,
                    "title":"Mens Cotton Jacket",
                    "price":55.99,
                    "description":"great outerwear jackets for Spring/Autumn/Winter, suitable for many occasions, such as working, hiking, camping, mountain/rock climbing, cycling, traveling or other outdoors. Good gift choice for you or your family member. A warm hearted love to Father, husband or son in this thanksgiving or Christmas Day.",
                    "category":"men's clothing",
                    "image":"https://fakestoreapi.com/img/71li-ujtlUL._AC_UX679_.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "id":4,
                    "title":"Mens Casual Slim Fit",
                    "price":15.99,
                    "description":"The color could be slightly different between on the screen and in practice. / Please note that body builds vary by person, therefore, detailed size information should be reviewed below on the product description.",
                    "category":"men's clothing",
                    "image":"https://fakestoreapi.com/img/71YXzeOuslL._AC_UY879_.jpg"
                }
        ],
      movimiento: 3
    }
  },
  methods: {
    arrowsAppear(){
      let buttonRight = document.querySelector(".categoryBox-btn-right")
      let buttonLeft = document.querySelector(".categoryBox-btn-left")
      buttonRight.style.right = 0;
      buttonLeft.style.left   = 0;
    },
    arrowsDisappear(){
      let buttonRight = document.querySelector(".categoryBox-btn-right")
      let buttonLeft = document.querySelector(".categoryBox-btn-left")
      buttonRight.style.right = '-50%';
      buttonLeft.style.left = '-50%';
    },
    prevSlide(){
      let grande  = document.querySelector('.manyProducts');
      let myimage = this.imageActive - 1; // Indice dentro del array siguiente al actual
      let ratio = (100 / this.datafiltrada.length) * -1; // si tengo 3 imagenes 100/3 * -1 = -33.33 de ratio por cada imagen
      let operacion = myimage * ratio; // -33.33 dividido el indice de la imagen a la que me muevo ej) 2*-33.33 = -66.66 
      if(myimage >= 0) {
        grande.style.transform = `translateX(${operacion}%)` //valor a aplicar para el efecto translate = -66.66% que es la imagen ubicacion de la imagen
        this.imageActive--
      }
    },
    nextSlide(){
      let grande      = document.querySelector('.manyProducts');
      let totalImages = this.datafiltrada.length - 1; //total de imagenes en el array -1 para que coincida con el indice
      let myimage     = (this.imageActive + 1) * this.movimiento; //imagen a la que quiero moverme (indiceActual + 1) * cantidad de saltos (Ej. Si me quiero mover de a 3 imagenes)
      let ratio       = (100 / this.datafiltrada.length) * -1; // 100 es el largo del array / la cantidad de items en el array * -1 para que el desplazamiento sea hacia la izquierda
      let operacion   = myimage * ratio; // Indice al que quiero moverme * el ratio necesario me devuelve el % de desplazamiento necesario para aplicar el efecto translateX
      let calculo     = (totalImages - totalImages % this.movimiento);

      if(myimage < calculo){
          console.log("primer if",myimage, calculo)
          
          grande.style.transform = `translateX(${operacion}%)`;
          this.imageActive++
      }else if(myimage === calculo){
          let resto = -100 - (ratio * 3);
          grande.style.transform = `translateX(${resto}%)`;
          this.imageActive++
      }else if (myimage > calculo){
          myimage                 = 0;
          let ratio               = (100 / this.datafiltrada.length) * -3;
          let operacion           = 0 * ratio;
          grande.style.transform  = `translateX(${operacion}%)`;
          this.imageActive        = 0;
      }      
    },
    setWidth() {
      //Esta función define el ancho que debe tener el contenedor que contiene
      //todas las imágenes para que luego podamos calcular el ratio basado en este ancho y la 
      //cantidad de imagenes contenidas dentro de este para movernos de 3 en 3 con el efecto translateX
      let container  = document.querySelector(".manyProducts");
      let totalImags = this.datafiltrada.length; // 20 imagenes
      let anchoImg   = (totalImags / this.movimiento) * 100; 
      container.style.width = anchoImg+"%"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filtro() {
      return this.datafiltrada = this.data.filter((res) => res.category == this.categoria)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setWidth;
  }
}
```

```css
.categoryBox-carrousel {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  max-width: 120em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px lightgray;
}
.container.categoryBox-navegador {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:3;
}
.categoryBox-carrousel .manyProducts {
  height:auto;
  padding:.2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transform:translateX(0%)
}
button.categoryBox-slider-1.v-btn.v-btn--is-elevated.v-btn--has-bg.theme--light.v-size--default{
  background-color:#fff;
  border:none;
  opacity: .7;
}

button.categoryBox-slider-1.categoryBox-btn-left.v-btn.v-btn--is-elevated.v-btn--has-bg.theme--light.v-size--default {
  position:absolute;
  left:-50%;
  transition:.5s ease-out;
}
button.categoryBox-slider-1.categoryBox-btn-right.v-btn.v-btn--is-elevated.v-btn--has-bg.theme--light.v-size--default {
  position:absolute;
  right:-50%;
  transition:.5s ease-out;
}

.categoryBox-carrousel .img {
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 2em);
  border-radius: 1em;
  height: auto;
  max-height:23em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  /*align-items: center;*/
}

.categoryBox-carrousel .img img{
  width:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center center;
}

span.p-title.subtitle-1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
    <div class="categoryBox-carrousel" @mouseover="arrowsAppear" @mouseleave="arrowsDisappear">
    <v-container class="categoryBox-navegador px-6">
        <v-app-bar flat color="rgba(0,0,0,0)" >
        <v-toolbar-title>
            <!-- (Titulo Opcional) -->
        </v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn class="categoryBox-slider-1 categoryBox-btn-left black" @click="prevSlide" fab>
            <v-icon class="white--text">mdi-arrow-left</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn class="categoryBox-slider-1 categoryBox-btn-right black" @click="nextSlide" fab>
            <v-icon class="white--text">mdi-arrow-right</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </v-app-bar>
    </v-container>
    <div class="badge error" style="width:50px;height:50px;position:absolute;z-index:999;border-radius:50px;display:flex;left:.66rem;top:.66rem;">
        <!-- (Icono Opcional) -->
        <span class="ma-auto white--text overline">sale</span>
    </div>
    <div class="manyProducts">
        <div  v-for="(img, key) in filtro" :key="key" :class="'img img-'+key">
            {{img.width}}
        <img :src="img.image" class="pa-5">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="details text-center pa-5">
        <span class="p-title subtitle-1">Lentes de sol para prueba #123654 color jade</span>
        <div class="text-center mt-4">
        <span class="text-decoration-line-through">ANTES $ 999.99</span>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <span class="price font-weight-bold" style="font-size:1.5rem;">HOY $ 850.00</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**DEJO UNA IMAGEN DE COMO SE VE CORRECTAMENTE EL COMPONENTE:**
Para lograr esto, solo tuve que eliminar los otros componentes de abajo y dejar uno solo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aguardo sus comentarios,

Muchas gracias

Comment: mira llegue hasta aca> let container  = document.querySelector(".manyProducts"); y para de leer.. porque si es vue... NO DEBES TOCAR EL DOM... para nada.. y de ahi, vienen absolutamente todos tus problemas.. un componente es como una pagina en si misma, autocontenida, y que hasta puede tener su propio CSS (le agregas scoped y listo)... ahora, fijate de sacar todo lo referido a tocar el DOM, y seguro se solucionan todos tu problemas...

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta! Mira he intentado lo siguiente. Del Mounted comente la linea que ejecuta la función `this.setWidth()` y en su lugar hice lo siguiente. Agregue una propiedad al componente llamada `ancho` y la definí como a continuacion. 'ancho:Number'. Y en donde voy a renderizar el componente le paso el mismo calculo que hacia en la funcion setWidth() pero dentro de la propiedad ancho y con un operador ternario. Asi: `:ancho="item.length > 3 ? (item.length * 100) / 3 : 100"` pero devuelve undefined, la propiedad la defini junto a categoria en la props.

Comment: AGREGO: luego del lado del componente utilizaría la propiedad con su valor al bindear un style asi `:style="ancho+'%'"`. pero nada!

Comment: yo no se donde hiciste eso.. pero veo un monton de cosas que tiene queryselector por todos lados.. o sea.. deberias hacer un monton de arreglos.. ahora, si tocaste un pedazo en particular, entonces mostra ese problema en particular...

Comment: @gbianchi Ya solucione gracias a tu comentario, reemplacé el document.querySelector que calculaba el ancho del contenedor por una función computada que a partir del largo del array resultante de filtrar por categoría calcula el ancho que debe tener. a su vez el desplazamiento lo deje igual pero accedo al contenedor a través de pasarle en las props el índice del elemento en el DOM. Por lo que al hacerle click solo afecto a ese elemento y no a los otros. Actualizo con la solución. Si quieres responder para aceptar tu respuesta.... Gracias

Comment: Agrega la solucion como respuesta... no es necesario que te de una, porque no sabria que tenes que solucionar (aparte de sacar todo queryselector)...

Comment: Ya lo hice, gracias. No puedo responder hasta mañana. Saludos

Comment: Igual, sigue habiendo queryselectors, y eso esta mal en vue... lo tendras que revisar mejor despues....